# libGdx - Drawing in a second viewport?

Tags: camera, libgdx, screen, viewport, stage

My Tiled 2D platformer game has a virtual size of 800x480 and I use a `StretchViewport` for my `Stage.` I set up the game camera as follows:

```
camera = new BoundedCamera(18, 10, map.width, map.height);
```

`BoundedCamera` simply extends `OrthographicCamera` with some additional code so that the map stays within the screen when the player moves towards the edge of the map.

In `render()` I do:

```
camera.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY());
camera.update();

tiledRenderer.setView(camera);
tiledRenderer.render();
```

Everything is working fine. Now I want to implement a minimap which I would like to display at (0, 380) having size (100, 100). So I created a second camera and a `ScalingViewport`:

```
minimapCamera = new OrthographicCamera(18, 10);

minimapViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, map.width, map.height, minimapCamera);
minimapViewport.setScreenBounds(0, 380, 100, 100);
```

And for rendering I do:

```
public void renderMinimap()
{
    minimapViewport.apply();

    minimapBatch.begin();

    minimapCamera.position.set(player.getX(), player.getY());
    minimapCamera.update();

    minimapRenderer.setView(minimapCamera);
    minimapRenderer();

    minimapBatch.end();

    level.getStage().getViewport().apply();
}
```

However, with the above, The minimap doesn't get 'clipped' within the bounds of the viewport. The minimap layer is being drawn slightly to the left and bottom of the the viewport bounds.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply call `setScreenBounds` on a viewport, because the changes you make will be overwritten when you call `update` on it. The built-in viewports in Libgdx all have very specific defined behaviors that are implemented in their `update` methods. Since you need different screen bounds, you will have to make your own Viewport class. You can subclass ScalingViewport and override the `update` method. Look at the source for ScalingViewport and modify the part where it calls `setScreenBounds`.